# Want to generate a counter for a series of 0s in a column

Tags: python, python-requests, counter

To explain clearly my data has temperature values and when the sensor is not registering any values, it will give continuous 0s. My interval is in ms and this will give me a string of 0s each time. And when a string of 0s come, I want the counter to increment from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on.

Essentially, I want the counter column as shown below

| No. | Temp | **Count** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80.0 | 0 |
| 2 | 81.6 | 0 |
| 3 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 4 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 6 | 81.6 | 1 |
| 7 | 80.0 | 0 |
| 8 | 83.7 | 0 |
| 9 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 10 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 11 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 12 | 81.6 | 1 |
| 13 | 81.6 | 0 |
| 14 | 80.0 | 0 |
| 15 | 83.7 | 0 |
| 16 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 17 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 18 | 0.00 | 0 |
| 19 | 81.6 | 1 |

I was thinking of

```
df['count'] = df.groupby((df['col'] == df['col'].shift(2)).cumsum()).cumcount()+1
```

But there has to be an easier way. Also, this can mess if my temperature values coincidentally adhere with this logic.

Comment: " this can mess if my temperature values coincidentally adhere with this logic" will be true for any solution.  If the temperature is actually 0.00 degrees how will you differentiate between that and a 'null'?  Other than that... what is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: My temperatures won't come near 0C, so that will not happen.  I may have more numbers of 0s. In this solution, if I have 6, then the counter will move twice.

Comment: I think what you're actually looking for is a 'rising edge'  i.e. 'detect whenever a non-zero temperature is preceded by a zero'

Comment: Also, why do you want to do this?  Do you want to know the total number of clusters of zero,  that would be easier to just calculate as a total than keeping a running total.

Comment: I am not aware of the number of zeros and they may or may not be equal every time. It is a part of designing a temperature/pressure sensor that will shoot real-time data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple boolean to keep track of if the last value was zero or not and increment a counter whenever the values stop becoming zero.

I saw that you used a PANDAS df but since your question said that you will be using realtime data, I decided to keep the code ambiguous so that you can apply it to your own use case.
Instead of a iterating through a list with a `for` loop, you can place the logic that connects to your sensor. And of course you can replace the print statement at the bottom with whatever you need.

```
nums = [80.0, 81.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.6, 80.0, 83.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 81.6]

zeroCount = 1
isZero = False
for num in nums:    #Can be whatever type of iteration you need
    if num == 0:
        isZero = True
    if isZero:
        if num != 0:
            zeroCount += 1
            isZero = False
    print("%.1f %d" % (num, zeroCount))
```

Running that code produces the output you tabulated in your question:

```
80.0 1
81.6 1
0.0 1
0.0 1
0.0 1
81.6 2
80.0 2
83.7 2
0.0 2
0.0 2
0.0 2
81.6 3
```